# time trends vs year fixed effects: is peaceful coexistence possible?

Tags: r, time-series, fixed, multicollinearity, fixest

How can I deal with collinearity between a time variable and year fixed effects? I have a panel model where the outcome is measure in three separate years. I am using OLS from the fixest package.

One of the variables is **gasprice**. It takes the same value for every unit *m* in time period *t*.

The problem arises when I incorporate yearly fixed effects. R drops **gasprice** on account of multicollinearity.

I’ve tried re-running the model without the year fixed effects and respecifying **gasprice** as a factor variable (**as.factor(gasprice)**)

Is there any way that I could keep **gasprice** and the year fixed effects without suffering from multicollinearity or having R drop **gasprice**?

Below some sample code to illustrate my issue.

Here is the data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(id=c(101,101,101,102,102,102),
year=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
gasprice=c(70,80,75,70,80,75), 
treatment=c(4,2,1,7,8,9), 
outcome=c(12,3,1,6,7,11))
```

Here is the model with gasprice and the unit and year fixed effects:

```
panel1 <- feols(outcome ~ treatment + gasprice|id+year, 
               panel.id= ~id+year,
               se="HC1",
                               data=subset(mydata))
```

Here is the error message I get from R:

`The variable 'gasprice' has been removed because of collinearity (see $collin.var).`

Thank you

Comment: `gasprice` appears to _be_ a year fixed effect since it doesn't vary across `id`s, naturally it get's dropped.

Comment: It is simply that your model that is misspecified, you cannot have the two. It's like adding a gender (or anything time invariant) variable in a model with individual fixed-effects, it makes no sense since all the variation from that variable is captured by the FE. BTW `The variable ... has been removed etc` is not an error message.